# What features to extract for handwritten character recognition?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

I am working on handwritten character recognition using neural networks. Currently I have segmented each character from the image. Now I want to extract features of each character so that I can feed them to the neural network. So what features should I extract from each character image?. Please suggest any sample code or procedure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which features can i use for handwritten OCR other than a downsampled binary grid of the image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888600/which-features-can-i-use-for-handwritten-ocr-other-than-a-downsampled-binary-gri)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you should extract features from the characters. All the classic an novel methods feed the ANN using a downsampled version of the binary image that contains the character.

One example (1993) is [this](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/feneric/charrecnn.html). There they use a 8x8 pixel version of the character as the ANN input. The question that @rafael-monteiro suggest in the comments also states that.

If your input images are big, maybe you want to try [this method](http://www.wieschoo.com/tutorials/botsuite/captcha-ocr-tutorial-neural-network/00746/), or if you desire to extract some features, [this work](http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece539/project/f03/sarkar-ppt.pdf) proposes some features, for exampl the angle of rotation of the parts of the character with more points or the aspect ratio of the character.